# Is it OK for an API to be split up into two DLLs, where one contains types and interfaces and the other contains the actual implemenations?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll

I am developing an API for controlling a printer-like device remotely over network. The client-part of the API will be given to our customer, so that he can integrate it into his process-control software.

I am using WCF for this task and need to pass data between the server-DLL and the client-DLL. With my current implementation/setup I am forced to put the corresponding types into a separate library to avoid a circular dependency between projects.

Since I am completely new to API design, my question is now:
Is it acceptable (e.g. in line with "best practices") to put types that the client-DLL uses (i.e. its dependencies) into a separate DLL, so that the consumer of our API needs to reference two DLLs?

If so, I would then also added the interface for my client in that DLL, to facilitate unit-testing. Do you see any issue with that?

Comment: Sounds like a good pattern to me - as also suggested by the fact that it helps unit testing. If you're controlling your device remotely using WCF, you may only need the interface/data-type DLL on the client (at least that's how it works in remoting) although I guess that depends on how much is in your implementation DLL.

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly acceptable.  We have a large application at work across multiple layers, and we put all our service contracts (interfaces) into a separate assembly (two, actually), and then both the service and the client reference the needed assemblie(s) for the implementations.

Comment: Yes!  Check out _[WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101)_ for further hints and tips.  Happy coding!